# node module not working on npm start or react-native run-android

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Getting Invalid regular expression error, the error log is as follows

```
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at blacklist (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js:34:10)
    at getBlacklistRE (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:66:59)
    at getDefaultConfig (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:82:20)
    at load (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:118:25)
    at Object.runServer [as func] (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\runServer.js:82:58)
    at Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:23)
    at Command.listener (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\Atin pal\project1\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project1@0.0.1 start: `react-native start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project1@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Atin pal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-31T02_34_07_153Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try to remove the node-module and install again: `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install`

Comment: from the project or the main nodejs

Comment: command isn't working

Comment: from the project

Comment: not working still

Answer (score 0):

Run "npm install react-scripts" command , some times it will work